# Typescript - get union type from values of field of another union type

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, is it possible to get a union type from the values of a field of another union type?

```
type MyUnionType = 
  | { foo: 'a', bar: 1 }
  | { foo: 'b', bar: 2 } 
  | { foo: 'c', bar: 3 }

// can I generate this automatically? 
// i.e. a union of the possible values of foo in MyUnionType?
type Foos = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

I'd hoped `Pick<MyUnionType, 'foo'>` might do it, but it doesn't quite work - it returns the type I want but nested under a `foo` field: `{ foo: 'a' | 'b' | 'c' }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type Foos = MyUnionType['foo']` [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0QFXNAvFAsAFBRQA+UA3lAGaqoBcUA5AIZMA0UARiwE6MBGKAF8iJclVoNmXDtz6MATCILEylGnUZMAxnJ78oAZhFEioSFABidLJbxwkaTNgDaTKUwC6Zwheg2qHYQyngACsg6ANYAPI4o6MGcHnRMAHzunl5AA) as long as every type has a `foo` field:

```
type MyUnionType = 
  | { foo: 'a', bar: 1 }
  | { foo: 'b', bar: 2 } 
  | { foo: 'c', bar: 3 }

type FooType = MyUnionType['foo']
// FooType = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

If you need to distribute over a heterogeneous union type you can [filter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) down to those types in the union with the field with:

```
type PickField<T, K extends string> = T extends Record<K, any> ? T[K] : never;
```

Which you can then [use](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0QFXNAvFAsAFBRQA+UA3lAGaqoBcUA5AIZMA0UARiwE6MBGKAF8iJclVoNmXDtz6MATCILEylGnUZMAxnJ78oAZhFj1VA4wAspwkVCQoAMTpZHeOEjSZsAbSZSTAC6RAD0oVAACryokLygzIFQACaoEADOUIiowFAQAB7I6bnoUA7QTJ4o6G4QTAB0UPQAtAAURPbYzq7YyniRyDoA1k7IEAA2yQA8Vd61nAF0TAB8YRHl3ai1fVAARCy76rtch+S7OrsdhBsDw6MT0xicANJ5+cAQiMmZxbzIiABzZZQPAYN4fL6ZABKEB0qF402enBYiBAwIA-FAML5nkEmlkIAA3CC8ADcQA):

```
type MyUnionType = 
  | { foo: 'a', bar: 1 }
  | { foo: 'b', bar: 2 } 
  | { foo: 'c', bar: 3 }
  | { bar: 4 }

type FooType = MyUnionType['foo']
// Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'MyUnionType'. :-(

type FooType2 = PickField<MyUnionType, 'foo'>
// type FooType2 = "a" | "b" | "c"

type PickField<T, K extends string> = T extends Record<K, any> ? T[K] : never;
// Alternatively, you could return `undefined` instead of `never`
// in the false branch to capture the potentially missing data
```

Answer (score 0):

What [Sean Vieira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135978/sean-vieira) has is great. Here's another way, slightly more verbose though:

```js
const ALL_TYPES =[
   { foo: 'a', bar: 1 },
   { foo: 'b', bar: 2 },
   { foo: 'c', bar: 3 }] as const

const ALL_FOOS = [...ALL_TYPES.map(t => t.foo)] as const;

type MyUnionType = typeof ALL_TYPES;
type FooType = typeof ALL_FOOS;
// FooType = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Comment: So this is an interesting approach, but not appropriate for my usecase because I don't want to do the runtime work of assembling the array of foos just to get the type. If you needed that array at runtime anyway, it might make more sense.

Comment: @davnicwil I totally get it ;) Thought it still makes sense to post it, there might be some other use cases for it (e.g. having big array of objects with many properties and selecting just few properties to turn that into a type). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To get the full set of all possible data, such as from an object literal type, use

```
type Intersect<T> =
    (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends
    (x: infer R) => any ? R : never
type ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T, TKey extends keyof Intersect<T> = keyof Intersect<T>> = T extends Record<TKey, any> ? ({
    [P in TKey]: T extends Record<P, any> ? (k: T[P]) => void : never
}[TKey] extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never) : never;
type Usage = { [K in keyof Intersect<TA1>]: ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<TA1, K> };
```